# How to force feed offset keyword a number calculated from table

Tags: mysql

I am trying something as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16062187).

As in this sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8d217/4 I created table

```
CREATE TABLE something (`some_column` int);
INSERT INTO something (`some_column`) VALUES (10),(20),(30),(40),(50);
```

I am trying to find median value so following is the query

```
select some_column from something order by some_column limit 1 offset 
(select floor(count(some_column) / 2) from something);
```

MySQL complains about the query part after offset; and it does accept hard coded values like any integer instead of sub-query like `(select floor(count(some_column) / 2) from something)`.

I am guessing the offset expects to get hard coded value and not a column with a value. I did try other options like using variables `@` but cannot make it work.

My question is; if I want to use a value from query operation in offset or limit and not a hard coded value, how should I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plan A:  Write a stored procedure to construct (via `CONCAT()`) the query you need, then use `prepare` and `executed`.

Plan B:  Create a temp table with an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column in order to number the rows.  Then look in that table for the answer.

Plan C:  Use @variables to count through the table.

Plan D:  http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#444